# MIPS program in 3 arrays one with the number another to rearrange them in ascending order and another to arrange them in descending order

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

i have been practicing my MIPS programming skills, as well as taking a class for computer architecture and i ran into a problem. these are the instructions: Write a MIPS program that:

1. Initializes an integer array
2. Sorts its elements in ascending order in a second array and prints them.
3. Sorts its elements in descending order in a third array and prints them....

This is what i have so far but I don't know how to populate array 3 with the descending order numbers

```
   .data
array: .space 100
input: .asciiz "Enter at least 4 integers: Enter the number 999 to exit \n"
output: .asciiz "The array in ascending order: \n"
commas: .asciiz ","

.text
.globl main
main:

la $a1, array   #loads a pointer to array into $a1
li $a2,9        #loads 9 into $a2
li $t0,0    
li $t1,999    

loops:

la $a0, input   #loads input text into $a
li $v0, 4       #loads 4 into $v0 (prints string) 
syscall         
li $v0, 5       #loads 5 into $v0 (read interger)
syscall         
beq $v0,$t1,swap
addi $t0,$t0,4   #add 4 to $t0, save to $t0
sw $v0, ($a1)    #stores input into array
addi $a1, $a1,4  #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1
j loops

swap:

la $t4, array    #loads array to $t4
la $t1, array    #loads array to $t1
addi $t1,$t1,4   #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1 
la $t8,array     #loads array to $t8
add $t8,$t0,$t8  #add $t8 to $t0, save to $t8
la $t9,array
add $t9,$t0,$t9  #add $t9 to $t0, save to $t9
addi $t9,$t9,-4  #subtracts 4 from $t9, save to $t9

loop:

lw $t2,($t4)     #load input into $t2
lw $t3,($t1)     #load input into $t3
bgt $t2,$t3,loop1 #if $t2 > $t3, go to loops
#blt $t2,$t3,loop1 #if $t2 < $t3, go to loops
sw $t3,($t4)     #store $t3 in $t4
sw $t2,($t1)     #store $t2 in $t1

loop1:

addi $t1,$t1,4    #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1
blt $t1,$t8,loop  #if $t1<$t8, go to loop
addi $t4,$t4,4    #add 4 to $t4, save to $t4
move $t1,$t4
addi $t1,$t1,4    #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1
blt $t4,$t9,loop  #if $t4<$t9, to go loop

print:

la $a1,array      #loads array to $a1
la $a0, output    #loads output to $a0
li $v0, 4         #loads 4 into #v0
syscall

loop2:

blez $t0, done   #if $t0<=0, go to done
li $v0, 1        #loads 1 into $v0
lw $a0, 0($a1)   #load an inout into $a0
syscall
la $a0, commas    #loads commas into $a0
li $v0, 4        #loads 4 into $v0
syscall
addi $a1, $a1, 4  #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1
addi $t0, $t0, -4 #subtracts 4 from #t0, save to $t0
j loop2

done:
j done
```

could anyone please help me out?

P.S. those comments are there as a guideline for myself

Comment: Please format the code! Select the code and use the `{}` button above the editor

Comment: What result are you getting? What result are you expecting? Is it right, or not? What part of your question isn't working right?

Comment: You comments are useless. Don't say what the instruction does, anyone who can read MIPS assembly can see that. Say what the *function* does, and *why* each instruction is needed.

Comment: Well as of now i got it in ascending order.. But its confusing me on how i can get it to go in descending order and store it in a second array. Sorry im new to mips and computer programming.